# Add html content to mysql die error?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm wanting to add html content in place of a mysql error, so rather than on fail when I get a mysql error with just a black background and the text 'error'.

```
mysql_query($query) or die ('error');
```

I want it to show this html content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="all" />


</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <h1>REGISTRATION WAS UNSUCCESFULL</h1><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <div class="textarea">
        <h3>Whoop! Good News we've successfully receieved your registration. So now what we've done, is sent you an email. In this email you will be guided through the final stage of account set-up.<br/><br/>Keep an eye on your inbox and follow the instructions. We hope to see you real soon ;-)</h3>
    </div>
        <div class="man_reg"><img src="../assets/img/help_support/man.png" alt="" width="210" height="214" /></div></div>
    <div id="progress_bar">
        <div id="progress"></div>
        <div id="progress_text">Registration Completed</div>
    </div>

    <style>
    .textarea{
        padding-left:55px;
        padding-right:55px;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .man_reg{
        margin-top:54px;
        margin-left:450px;
    }

    </style>    
</body>
</html>
```

Would I not just insert the html content within the brackets of the  mysql or die error?

like so:

```
mysql_query($query) or die ('HTML CONTENT HERE!');
```

Comment: Why are you still using `mysql_` functions? They are deprecated and better alternatives exist.

Answer (score 1):

Just store your html content in a variable and use that variable in `die`

```
$error = "<html>your html content</html>";

mysql_query($query) or die ($error);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `or die()`. `mysql_query` **returns** `false` on failure, so work with that:

```
$result = mysql_query(...);

if (!$result) {

    // do anything necessary to display a page here,
    // maybe include() an external file

} else {

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The better solution is to have an error page with that content and just redirect user to it with the following code:

```
$res = mysql_query($query);
if (!$res) {
    header('Location: http://yourdomain.com/error.html');
    die(); // just to end up the execution
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically just put the content inside the brackets, but a more elegant way would be having a separate `error.html` template and `include()` ing that. This way, your code won't be polluted with tons of markup.

error.html (simplified):

```
<html><head></head><body><?php echo $error; ?></body></html>
```

PHP code:

```
$result = mysql_query(....);

if (!$result)
 { 
   $error = mysql_error();
   include "error.html";
   die(); 
 }
```

Note that it's bad style to display errors in production environments. You may want to show the exact error message while developing, and a generic "An error has occurred" page when the project is public.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function too for this

```
function dieerr() {
echo '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="all" />


</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
<h1>REGISTRATION WAS UNSUCCESFULL</h1><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<div class="textarea">
    <h3>Whoop! Good News we\'ve successfully receieved your registration. So now what we\'ve done, is sent you an email. In this email you will be guided through the final stage of account set-up.<br/><br/>Keep an eye on your inbox and follow the instructions. We hope to see you real soon ;-)</h3>
</div>
    <div class="man_reg"><img src="../assets/img/help_support/man.png" alt="" width="210" height="214" /></div></div>
<div id="progress_bar">
    <div id="progress"></div>
    <div id="progress_text">Registration Completed</div>
</div>

<style>
.textarea{
    padding-left:55px;
    padding-right:55px;
    text-align:center;
}
.man_reg{
    margin-top:54px;
    margin-left:450px;
}

</style>    
</body>
</html>';
exit;
}
```

And if you have this then use it like that:

```
mysql_query($query) or dieerr();
```